# Removing the background of a frame animation in Android

Tags: android, timer, android-animation, background-color, animationdrawable

How can I *remove* the **background** of a frame animation (or set it to be *transparent*)?

When I set the background colour in the **xml** layout file to be transparent, it turns up **black** when running it.

When I [setBackgroundColor(0);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) in the **Java code** I get the following **exception**:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable`

/res/layout/dialog_loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_black_semitransparent" >
    <!-- The background of this LinearLayout is so that there is 
         a semi transparent black overlay over the application content 
         while the loading animation plays -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_loading"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

/res/anim/frame_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The animation is defined by the animation-list element. The oneshot attribute defines whether or not the animation loops.
Each image is placed in a separate item elementwith the drawable attribute specifying the image file in /res/drawable/. 
The duration attribute specifies the time delay between images.
 -->

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00000" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00002" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00004" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00006" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00008" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00010" android:duration="75" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00012" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00014" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00016" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00018" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00020" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00022" android:duration="75" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00024" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00026" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00028" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00030" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00032" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00034" android:duration="75" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00036" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00038" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00040" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00042" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00044" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00046" android:duration="75" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00048" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00050" android:duration="75" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loading_1_00052" android:duration="75" />

</animation-list>
```

Java code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout to use as dialog or embedded fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, container, false);

    //Get the ImageView 
    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_loading);
    //set the animation as the background of the ImageView
    //the animation is described in /res/anim/frame_animation.xml

    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frame_animation);

    img1.setBackgroundColor(0);   // <---- get error here

    //create an instance of AnimationLoop
    AnimationLoop animLoop = new AnimationLoop(img1);

    //create a timer
    Timer t = new Timer(false);
    //schedule the animation loop
    t.schedule(animLoop, 100);

    return view;
}

//our animation handler
class AnimationLoop extends TimerTask
{
    ImageView img1;
    AnimationLoop(ImageView im)
    {
        img1 = im;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation1 = (AnimationDrawable) img1.getBackground();

        // Start the animation (looped play back by default).
        frameAnimation1.start();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
06-07 12:04:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(6581): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
06-07 12:04:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(6581): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
06-07 12:04:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(6581):     at za.co.domain.client.product.tools.ProgressDialogFragment$AnimationLoop.run(ProgressDialogFragment.java:79)
06-07 12:04:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(6581):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

**EDIT:**

See screenshot[image] from when the android:background="#0000" as suggested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0000" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#0000" >        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_loading"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#0000" />        
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Animation bg is turning black while running because frame images used for animation have black bg i guess. So, if u change just in xml, it wl b same(black bg) while running animation

Answer (score 1):

Try set

```
android:background="@null"
```

in your `FrameLayout`, remove the line `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` from your `imageView`.

---

UPDATE

You can also try adding this:

```
AnimationDrawable drawable = (AnimationDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.R.anim.frame_animation);
img1.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Thanks Neoh, but this doesn't work. The background is still black. I think it's because of this: img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frame_animation); but I don't know what else??

Answer (score 1):

ImageView has method setImageResource which corresponds to the image being drawn in the foreground. You have to set background to be transparent as some have pointed out already and call

```
img1.setImageResource(R.anim.frame_animation);
```

on your ImageView.

Also personally I would try to avoid having 52 bitmaps loaded into memory at once. animation-lists loads them all. This will probably work only on newer phones depending on image sizes.

Btw, it all works if your frames are on a transparent background. If they're not and you either need to make them to be or if it's not possible, you can implement a custom view which would draw bitmaps directly on a scale using PorterDuff blending mode. See documentation on [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) and [PorterDuffColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

For transparent background use `android:background="#0000"`. `#0000` denotes **transparent background**. Please note that if you use this in `FrameLayout` then you will have `background_black_semitransparent` as your background. If you want complete transparency then replace this with the above code.

Comment: This doesn't work on my side - the background is still there. I've checked that the png images do NOT have a background. So where is this background coming from? I've put android:background="#0000" in the root LinearLayout (tested - the background is still there), then I added it to the FrameLayout AND the ImageView and the background is still there :(

Comment: consider this, you have 3 different components in xml each has its background. Each Layout is like a layer. `LinearLayout` is at the `bottom` then middle is `FrameLayout` and top most is `ImageView`. Now as far as transparency is considered. Consider putting a transparent glass as the base of each layer. 
Now if you put `ImageView`'s background as a glass then  you can see the background of `FrameLayout`. Now if you set `FrameLayout`'s background as glass then you can see background of `LinearLayout` since both `ImageView` and and `FrameLayout` are glass.

Comment: If you want to just show the `ImageView` with no background at all. Then set the background of `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout` as transparent ie. `#0000`. Also set the background of the `ImageView` as transparent .
Since you are using `FrameLayout` your `ImageView` might not scale to the complete width and height of the `FrameLayout`. Thus the left space is filled with a background. This is happening with me too.

Comment: But I have had all set to android:backgroud="#0000" and I still saw a background when running the app. I checked that the images themselves do not have a background - just what has to be seen in each frame.

Comment: @Enke can you post any screenshot?

Comment: Please see the screenshot. For privacy purposes I had to change the actual content of the image, but the just of it is there

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried setting the background to transparent using an `R.id.color` of `#0000` or `#00000000` before you do the `setBackgroundResource`? In other words switch around your two background setting lines of code.